# UNIX multi-variable definition on a single line

Tags: linux

I am wondering if it's possible to have a single line command that echoes  a value at the end.

Example:

```
let N=444,M=555,O=N*M,echo "$0"
```

Answer (score 3):

Sure:

```
N=444;M=555;echo "$(($N * $M))"
```

or

```
N=444;M=555;O="$(($N * $M))";echo $O
```

or

```
N=444;M=555;echo $N*$M | bc -l
```

Don't forget to run:

```
unset N && unset M
```

after your one-liner so your shell won't get polluted with useless variables.

Comment: so could it be N=444;M=555;O=N*M;echo “$O”     if i wanted to declare O as the product of M & N

Comment: Yes, it would be `N=444;M=555;O="$(($N * $M))";echo $O`